# bin node search in map

Tags: c, tree, nodes

I try to search in a map I created.  Each cell have 3 branches. When A is the closest, B after and C is the farthest. I'm trying to find the shortest route. 
It is possible, for instance, that b->c->c->a is closer than a->a->a->a->a.
What should I do?

```
gag *pathfinder(gag *root, int choice)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        printf_s("the map didnt exits.");
        getchar();
        exit(1);
    }
    if (choice == root->index)
    {
        printf_s("(%d,%d)", root->x, root->y);
        return root;
    }
    if (choice != root->index)
        if (root->A != NULL)
        {
            if (root->A->index != NULL && root->A->index == choice)
                ;

            else
            {
                pathfinder(root->A, choice);
            }
        }
        else if (choice != root->index)
            if (root->B != NULL)
            {
                if (root->B->index != NULL && root->B->index == choice)
                    ;                                               // printf_s("(%d,%d)->", root->B->x, root->B->y);
                else
                {
                    pathfinder(root->B, choice);
                }
            }

            else if (choice != root->index)
                if (root->C != NULL)
                {
                    if (root->C->index != NULL && root->C->index == choice)
                        ;                                               //
                    printf_s("(%d,%d)->", root->C->x, root->C->y);
                    else
                    {
                        pathfinder(root->C, choice);
                        printf_s("(%d,%d)->", root->C->x, root->C->y);
                    }
                }

}


gag* path(gag *map, gag* tree, int len) {
    char temp = map->index;
    gag* hold;
    tree->index = temp;
    static int c = -1;
    int *close;
    c++;

    (map)->index = 'v'; // Mark as visited.
    (map)->entries++;
    //go A
    if (!map->A || map->A->index == 'v' || map->A->entries == 3)
        tree->A = NULL;
    else {
        hold = malloc(sizeof(gag)*len);
        d_p_s(map, hold);
        tree->A = path(map->A, hold, len);
    }
    //go B
    if (!map->B || map->B->index == 'v' || map->B->entries == 3)
        tree->B = NULL;
    else {
        hold = malloc(sizeof(gag)*len);
        d_p_s(map, hold);
        tree->B = path(map->B, hold, len);
    }
    //go C
    if (!map->C || map->C->index == 'v' || map->C->entries == 3)
        tree->C = NULL;
    else {
        hold = malloc(sizeof(gag*)*len);
        d_p_s(map, hold);
        tree->C = path(map->C, hold, len);
    }

    map->index = temp;
    return tree;
}
```

Comment: Your code is either mis-indented or missing braces.  For example, `else if (choice != root->index)` is associated with `if (root->A != NULL) { … }` and not with `if (choice != root->index)` which the indentation seems to suggest.  You should avoid such nested `if` statements.  When they're necessary, use braces to ensure that they are correctly nested, and indent the code to reflect that.  I'm not even going to try to make any guesses at what the code should be.

Comment: Your question is inscrutable.  It is not clear how `a->a->a->a->a` could be shorter than `a` — but it also isn't clear what the data structure is, or how it works.  I can guess that English isn't your first language, but you will need to clarify your question.  Showing the definition of the data structure might help.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: I changed my mind — I've taken the code for your first function and run it through a formatter (Uncrustify), and pasted the result.  The nesting of the `if` statements gives me the heebie-jeebies — I'm 99% confident that it's wrong, but I've no idea what it is going to take to make it right.  The second function is indented in an orthodox manner; that doesn't have a layout problem.